# Can't create/write to file

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian, ispmanager

Здравствуйте. MySQL стал выбивать ошибку:

> Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_7dfa_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)

погуглив я понял, что не хватает места, но в
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит `isp manager`. Я плохо понимаю как он работает, в общем там у каждого юзера есть своя папка temp, лежит в `/var/www/USER/data/mod-tmp`
там видимо тонна файлов, я не могу ее открыть через фтп и даже не могу узнать сколько она весит. В ней видимо сессии `php` хранятся.

**В общем как устранить ошибку? Может очистить как то папку?** Только чтобы ничего не сломалось...

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `ls -la /tmp/ | grep "sql_"`

Comment: Правильная ссылка из удаленного ответа -- [Необычное переполнение жесткого диска или как удалить миллионы файлов из одной папки](https://habrahabr.ru/post/152193/) (если ссылка протухнет, то суть -- читайте  [man getdents](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) и пишете удаление этих файлов на Си).

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте количество свободных inod'ов - возможно они закончились.

## df -i

Comment: А на каком девайсе надо смотреть?

Comment: @0xdb, просто введенная `df -i` покажет все девайсы, если нужно, например, на том, в котором `/tmp`,  то наберите `df -i /tmp` (заодно узнаете на каком девайсе этот каталог)

Comment: Автору вопроса интересно по-видимому /tmp. @Dmitriy Isaev дополните ваш ответ на основе комментария - avp.